# A simple least square optimization

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I came across an unconstrained least square optimization problem as follows,

$\underset{a_i,\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{minimize}}\quad\sum_i\left\Vert\mathbf{y}_i-a_i\mathbf{x}\right\Vert_2^2$.

I wonder is it possible to solve it in closed form? Thanks

Comment: Are the variables in real or complex field?

Comment: @AlexSilva Complex domain. Is it a big issue here?

Comment: Can you manipulate $a_i$ and $x$ both? It's very strange as you can always choose them in such a way to make the sum equal to $0$

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov Yes, we can manipulate $a_i$ and $\mathbf{x}$ both. $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector without the index $i$. How can we choose them such that the sum equal to 0?

Comment: @seuhoww excuse me, I didn't get $y_i$ are vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$L(\mathbf{x},a_i ) =\sum_i\left\Vert\mathbf{y}_i-a_i\mathbf{x}\right\Vert_2^2  = \sum_i \left(\Vert \mathbf{y}_i\Vert_2^2 - a_i \mathbf{y}_i^{H}\mathbf{x} -a_i^{*}\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{y}_i+ |a_i|^2 \Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2\right),$$

where $^*$ and $^H$ are the conjugate and the conjugate transpose operators.

Thus, the stationary points satisfy

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \sum_i -a_i \mathbf{y}_i^{H} + |a_i|^2\mathbf{x}^{H} = \mathbf{0}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial a_i} = -\mathbf{y}_i^{H}\mathbf{x} + a_i^{*}\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2 = \mathbf{0}$$

From the second equation, $a_i = \dfrac{\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{y}_i}{\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2}$. Substituting partially in the first one, we have

$$\sum_i \left(-\dfrac{\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{y}_i}{\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2}\mathbf{y}_i^{H} + |a_i|^2\mathbf{x}^{H}\right) = \mathbf{0} \implies \left(\sum_i \mathbf{y}_i \mathbf{y}_i^{H}\right)\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x},$$ with $\lambda = \sum_i|a_i|^2\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2$, which is an *eigenvalue problem*.

**EDIT - Additional details:**

Notice that the objective can be written as

$$\sum_i \left(\Vert \mathbf{y}_i\Vert_2^2 - a_i \mathbf{y}_i^{H}\mathbf{x} -a_i^{*}\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{y}_i+ |a_i|^2 \Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2\right)= \sum_i \left(\Vert \mathbf{y}_i\Vert_2^2 - a_i a_i^{*}\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2 -a_i^{*}a_i \Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2 + |a_i|^2 \Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2\right)$$
$$ = \sum_i \left(\Vert \mathbf{y}_i\Vert_2^2 - |a_i|^2 \Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_2^2\right) = \sum_i \left(\Vert \mathbf{y}_i\Vert_2^2\right) - \lambda.$$

Thus, take the maximum eigenvalue to minimize the objective.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply.
I got the same results for the stationary points conditions, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i}=0\Rightarrow a_i=\frac{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{y}_i}{||\mathbf{x}||_2^2},\\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=0\Rightarrow \mathbf{x}=\frac{\sum_ia_i^*\mathbf{y}_i}{\sum_i|a_i|^2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then, I don't know how to solve $\mathbf{x}$. In your reply, $\lambda$ is also related to $\mathbf{x}$, is it possible to solve for $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: I substitute the first stationary condition to the second one and got the equation in $\mathbf{x}$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}=||\mathbf{x}||_2^2\frac{\sum_i\mathbf{y}_i^H\mathbf{xy}_i}{\sum_i|\mathbf{y}_i^H\mathbf{x}|^2}
\end{equation}
When I left-multiply $\mathbf{x}^H$ to both sides of the equation, it will always be an identity equation, which prevents me from sloving for $\mathbf{x}$. Am I right?

Comment: @seuhoww, your last equation in $\mathbf{x}$ is correct, but you cannot solve on  $\mathbf{x}$ analytically without using an eigenvalue decomposition. Left-multiplying  $\mathbf{x}$ to both sides and obtaining an identity equation, only shows that this equation is right, but it is impossible "isolate" the vector $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then how can we do the EVD with $\lambda$ also being a function of $\mathbf{x}$? Could you please elaborate a bit? Furthermore, if we can solve for $\mathbf{x}$, then $\mathbf{x}$ will be still related to $a_i$, then how can we get the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @seuhoww, I have edited the answer with more details. Notice that the solution does not depend on the $\| \mathbf{x}\|_2$ nor on $|a_i|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I get your point.

Comment: @seuhoww, If you accepted the answer, please click on the checkmark and/or upvote it.

Comment: Sure. Have done it. Thanks again.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249870/submatrix-quotient, which may fall in your area. Thank you so much.